# Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am receiving a strange error when I am trying to perform an assertion via cypress and just need some assistance. All I am trying to do is display that a selection is added into the bet slip.

The error I am receiving is:

```
get Object{5}

assert expected { Object (0, length) } to be visible

Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
```

This happens in this step:

```
And ("The number of elements is {string}", (number) => {
  cy.get(elements.selection()).should('be.visible').should('have.length', number);
})
```

The element it points to is:

```
class Elements {

    selection(){
        return cy.get('.__selection')
    }
}

export default Elements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've doubled up on the `cy.get()`

```js
cy.get(elements.selection()).should('be.visible')

selection(){
  return cy.get('.__selection')
}
```

Either

```js
elements.selection().should('be.visible')

selection(){
  return cy.get('.__selection')
}
```

Or

```js
cy.get(elements.selection()).should('be.visible')

selection(){
  return '.__selection'
}
```